# Word after a particular word in a string

Tags: shell, unix

I have string say e.g. ab_abc_bbb_ccc_ssss_pppp, I want the word after ccc i.e. ssss from the string, how to achieve the same using unix command

Comment: There are many ways to do this but you should post your attempts to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
echo "ab_abc_bbb_ccc_ssss_pppp" | sed 's/.*ccc_\([^_]*\).*/\1/'
```

**explanation**

```
s/          # substitute
.*ccc_      # find search pattern
\([^_]*\)   # save all chars without '_' into arg1 (\1)
_.*/        # ignore trailing chars
\1/         # print \1
```

**output**

```
ssss
```